# How to set a word-break in proper manner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have and issue regarding **word-break** here is my **CSS and html** code. Using **Bootstrap-4**

In this i have to set a word like connected with proper word ending please help me a with proper solution.

Please Check this SS Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h2Jz.png

```
<!--CSS -->

.main-img img {
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
}

.main-img button {
  background: #edf3fb;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: normal;
  border: none;
}

.main-img span {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

<!-- Code Structure -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-xl-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 p-3">
          <div class="align-self-center main-img ml-auto mr-auto">
            <button class="d-block m-auto"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJld.png" class="align-content-center img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" alt="icon-img">
  </button>
            <span>Home Improvements</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 p-3">
          <div class="align-self-center main-img ml-auto mr-auto">
            <button class="d-block m-auto"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJld.png" class="align-content-center img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" alt="icon-img">
  </button>
            <span>Home Improvements</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 p-3">
          <div class="align-self-center main-img ml-auto mr-auto">
            <button class="d-block m-auto"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJld.png" class="align-content-center img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" alt="icon-img">
  </button>
            <span>Home Improvements</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with stuff like this, you need also to remember the importance of UX UI and microcopy when doing web development.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers sadly can't figure out how to properly separate words by themselves.
But if you have access to the html you can add `&shy;` where you would want the word to be separated if there is not enough space.

Else you can add `hypens: auto;` in your css, but then the separation might not be on the right place.

More infos:
https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens